# How to set UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, flowlayout

A UIViewController maintains a reference to a UICollectionView. The controller should modify the built-in flow layout using the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

It's pretty easy to set the view's data source to self:

**MyViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
}
```

But how do I set the controller to be the delegate flow layout of the view?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.collectionView.dataSource= self;
    // self.collectionView.??? = self; 
}
```

I've tried:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.collectionView.dataSource= self;
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = self; 
}
```

But I get the error: "Incompatible pointer types assigning ...".

The collection header file looks like this:

**MyViewController.h**

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
```

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Just `self.collectionView.delegate = self;`. Note that `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` inherits from `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

I admit it caught me off guard at first.

Oh and this will only work if `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout` is actually set to your flow layout. (or set with `initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:`)

Comment: @JohnEstropia, sorry for question, but how to init custom layout in code? I see examples with storyboards but not with code itself. What should I do?

Comment: probably, `self.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()`, `self.collectionViewLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init]`

Answer (score 15):

According to previous answer just example of use. It really not clear but I can show how it works:

```
@interface PrettyViewController()<UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource>
    //some code
@end

@implementation PrettyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionView.delegate = self;//bingo! right here
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 20.0);
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

My two cents for **macOS Mojave - Swift**

(I've fallen here searching for `NSCollectionView`... I do know question was about `UICollectionView`..)

All said above (specifying delegate implies cell size, too) is correct for macOS, too.

*NOTE*: If You write:

```
class MyViewController:
    NSCollectionViewDelegate,
    NSCollectionViewDataSource,
    **NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** 
{
```

the method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, 
                      layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, 
               sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSSize
```

**will** be called.

If removed, no delegate method will be called. (as class does not obey to the protocol).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use this in swift
just use this

UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in your controller delegate or make an extension of your controller for this after that add this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return  CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width - 10) / 2, height: (collectionView.frame.size.width - 10) / 2)
}
```