# UICollectionView - distance between cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, storyboard, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I'm using a UICollectionView with the cell width of 67, right now I am using a flow layout.

I have 3 cells in a row with 30px space between cells. How can make that distance less, so that I can fit four cells in a row? Does this method have something to do with it?

```
 - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
 {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
 }
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This  `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate` method will help you..

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section  
  {
    return 10; // This is the minimum inter item spacing, can be more
  }
```

One more if you need more space to arrange your cells adjust the `edgeInsets` also

Comment: For anyone having trouble getting started with `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12925529/168594).

Comment: This sets the minimum, but how to set the maximum?

Comment: Only can guarantee the minimumInteritemSpacing. You cannot set the maximum or the actual inter item spacing. The actual value is depends on the item size,sectionInset and the minimumInteritemSpacing. So adjust these values to get the appropriate behaviour. Collection view flow layout is dynamically deciding the actual value.

Comment: Actually it's `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Answer (score 21):

You can configure spacing between cells or rows by using following properties.
1) For setting space between rows.

```
[self.collectionView setMinimumLineSpacing:5];
```

2) For setting space between items/cells.

```
[self.collectionView setMinimumInteritemSpacing:5];
```

You can also configure it from InterfaceBuilder(IB). Just select UICollectionView from storyboard/Xib file and click in **Size Inspector** as specified in below image.  [image]

Answer (score 17):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23542017/2684720).
You need to change *minimumInteritemSpacing* and *minimumLineSpacing*.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flow.itemSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);
flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
flow.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
mainCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flow;
```

Answer (score 11):

No, it doesn't. Just change the layout's `minimumInteritemSpacing`.

Comment: What method should i place that in? Im new to collection views.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewFlowLayout/minimumInteritemSpacing

Answer (score 6):

You can use delegate method like:-
for changing the space between cells in a section.

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
```

For showing top,bottom y padding between cells of different sections.

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
```

// Layout: Set Edges
//setting insets for cell

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section 
//top,left,botttom,right
```

Answer (score 3):

**swift 3.0**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if DEVICE_IDIOM == .pad {
        return 15.0
    }
    else {
        return 10.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue..

In my case I needed a retangular cell.

To achieve the desired result I used the *UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout*.

This is my implementation of one of the method:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)/3.0f;
    return CGSizeMake(width, (width * 1.1f));
}
```

This worked fine for me! I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
            collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                            minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

 return 10
}
```