# how to set equal space for all screen for uicollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i am using swift 2.o uicollection view. I did all spacing for left, right,top,bottom,cell, line spacing as 8 px. But when i run in 5s my collection view is ok. But when i run my app in above 6,6s screen i am seeing many gap between each cell. I need four cell in each row..

here is my 5s screen :

[image]

Here is my 6 screen :

[image]

How can i set equal space like 5s screen for all screen Please help me out.

Thanks !

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

return CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width/4) - 20, (self.view.frame.size.width/4) - 20);

    }
```

Comment: Can you post your layout constraints?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325277/how-to-set-cell-spacing-and-uicollectionview-uicollectionviewflowlayout-size-r

Comment: constraints for image and label???

Comment: use this https://github.com/foursquare/FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayout

Answer (score 0):

Use `size classes` for that. Click [here](https://digitalleaves.com/blog/2014/09/towards-responsive-ios-design-i-beyond-autolayout-and-size-classes/) for more information. Also set your item sizes with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

Comment: yes i add some code for that, in that height is very small.please see my updated post