# Tile-like app using UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to build an app that look-like a tile-based app (a bit windows style) and I'm new to UICollectionView.

This is what I'm trying to achieve :

[image]

The idea is that today, I know that I have 6 icons to display in each of these cells. But tomorrow could be 8, 10, etc.

So instead of a static 6-imageview-based storyboard, I'd like to have a collection view for its flexibility.

However I could not find how to constrained my cells relatively to the container view. Xcode only lets me specify a fixed point-based size. Furthermore, even if I play with the minimum spacing between cells, I observe gaps for a value of 0.

What I've done so far :

- created a UICollectionViewController in storyboard
- created a small custom class to handle my cells (basically an outlet for the image view inside and a label)
- I let the properties "item" and "layout" values to respectively "1" and "Flow" in the UICollectionView Attributes inspector (I have a reusable identifier)

Can someone help on this ?

Comment: Your question is not clear as to what u r looking for

Comment: @BasanthVerma : I'm looking for a code or storyboard-based way to have 3 lines and 2 column without spacing that fills my view like shown above

Comment: u mean 3 rows and 2 columns?

Comment: @BasanthVerma yes sorry for the bad english there

Comment: No problem, my english isn't that good as well. I got what u r looking for. Will be adding the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: The answer that i've added can support any number of cells as per the picture u've shared

Comment: @BasanthVerma thank you for your answer. I was looking for Swift code so i'll have to work on it before I tell you if this actually worked !

Comment: https://github.com/cp-satish-v/MosaicLayoutDemo

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this,

```
  let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth/3, height: screenWidth/3)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

Use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to achieve this.

You can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325277/how-to-set-cell-spacing-and-uicollectionview-uicollectionviewflowlayout-size-r) for more detail. :)

**Update(as per comment) :**

you should override datasource of collectionview.

`numberOfItemsInSection` should return 2 and `umberOfSectionsInCollectionView` should return 3

hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Got 2 rows and 3 columns instead of the opposite, but if I play with itemSize it will distord the cell icon, any tip ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the ***programmatic answer*** to your question:

Create a class by extending **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** .

In the implementation file of our class, add the following methods:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       //overriding default values
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    }
    return self;
}
```

//Method to arrange ur cells properly

```
- (NSArray *) layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
//Returns an array of UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes objects representing the layout information for the cells and views.
NSArray *attribArray = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

for(int i = 1; i < [attribArray count]; ++i) {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *currentLayoutAttributes = attribArray[i];
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *prevLayoutAttributes = attribArray[i - 1];
   //No separation between the cells
    NSInteger maximumSpacing = 0;
    NSInteger origin = CGRectGetMaxX(prevLayoutAttributes.frame);

    if((origin + maximumSpacing + currentLayoutAttributes.frame.size.width) < self.collectionViewContentSize.width) {
        CGRect frame = currentLayoutAttributes.frame;
        frame.origin.x = origin + maximumSpacing;
        currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame;
    }
}
return attribArray;
}
```

//If collection view bound changes, it will recompute all of its layout attributes

```
 - (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    return YES;
}
```

> Set this custom class as a flow layout to your collection view,
>
> ```
>  YourFLowLayoutCustomClass *flowlayout=[[YourFLowLayoutCustomClass alloc] init];
> ```
>
> _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:frame collectionViewLayout:flowlayout];

Now in the class where you have implemented the **UICollectionView**, implement the following method if you have not already done it:

```
 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/3);
}
```

This will set the size of the cells as per the Picture you shared. Cheers!