# UICollection horizontally scroll, so reduce the space between cell item

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2, uicollectionviewcell

I take UICollectionView and set horizontal scroll. Now In this one image view is there, All working perfect except cell spacing. In collectionView I set the Minimum Spacing for cells 0 (Zero). But still Spaces is there.

My output is like that:

[image]

But I need this type of output:

[image]

And one more thing is that I refer so many answer but still no idea what to do. I use Xcode 7.0 so I need solution in swift 2.0 and if possible then also request to give answer in swift 3.0.

Comment: Did you try it with code? check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325277/how-to-set-cell-spacing-and-uicollectionview-uicollectionviewflowlayout-size-r

Comment: func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 155, height: 155)
    }
I also put this method of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout but still not working..

Comment: are u sure deleagte are getting called??

Comment: Try in `viewDidLoad` shown in that link I gave.

Comment: Yaa.. I put the break point into that.. So method called but not working.

Comment: @Dhamesh I already try this code but when I put that code so my scrolling became vertically..

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to  set collectionview flowlayout delegate:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: collectionViewTable.bounds.size.width/2 - 20, height: 160)

         }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
    {
        return  UIEdgeInsetsMake( 5,  14, 5,  14)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20;
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20;
    }
```

Comment: I refer so many code but all about vertically scroll. My scrolling is horizontally

Comment: u have to change values and test   i didnt tested as per your requirement  can u show the screen shot?

Comment: Ya.. thats working but when I put code in viewDidload() with help of UICollectionViewFlowLayout So that time not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150451/discussion-between-ramesh-and-niravs).

Comment: I have only problem of more spacing between cellItem.

Comment: increase item width   and try changing minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex , minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex methods decrease and check can u show screen shot

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can set cells and lines spacing from size inspector.

You can also set from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets`

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat`

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat`

Answer (score 0):

Add following methods in your code and manipulate until your desire output.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: CGFloat(collectionView.frame.size.width/ 2 - 5), height: CGFloat(135)) // 2 is indicates number of cell in row
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.0
    }

    func  collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                         layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                         minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is all good. But I don't gate the out put what I want so I try  new thing that give - minus value

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return -20;
    }
```

So only using this one method with minus value and I get my desired output.
Thanks to all who try to solve this bug for me...