# UICollection View custom layout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to layout a UICollectionView like the mock-up I have drawn in the photo(also showing the index of each item).

I did some research on UICollectionViewLayout and also implement some of the methods but the result is nothing

[image]

```
enter code here

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let padding: CGFloat =  50
        let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
        if indexPath.row == 3{
            return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize, height: collectionViewSize/2)
        }
        else{
        return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: collectionViewSize/2)
        }
    }
```

[using above function i get result shown in image...but i not want 
    3rd number cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtZpK.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For this layout overriding https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview should be enough.

Comment: can you give me any example...and i want to design layout for iPhone as well as iPad

Comment: It may help you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325277/how-to-set-cell-spacing-and-uicollectionview-uicollectionviewflowlayout-size-r

Comment: thank you very much..it worked

Comment: First cell is at row 0. We start with index 0 in most of programming language, not 1, so `if indexPath.row == 3{` should be `if indexPath.row == 2{`. Note that with collectionView we tend to prefers using `item` instead of `row`.

Comment: yes indexpath.row == 2 work

Answer (score 1):

try as following:

1. Declare a `CGFloat` for the margin at the top of the class and set it in your `viewDidLoad()` like this:

   ```
   var margin: CGFloat!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       // set your margin to whatever suits you
       margin = 2

   }
   ```
2. Override `minimumInteritemSpacingForSection` function and set it to return your margin variable:

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return margin
   }
   ```
3. Override sizeForItem function as the following code:

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

       if indexPath.item < 3 {
          if indexPath.item > 0 && indexPath.item == 2 {
           return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
          } else {

             return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width / 2) - margin, height: 100)
          }
       } else {
       if (indexPath.item + 1) % 3 == 0 {
           return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
       } else {
           return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width / 2) - margin, height: 100)
       }
    }

   }
   ```

Hope it helps :)