# UICollectionView cell spacing not working anymore

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have been working on this app for a few days, I am working on laying out a UICollectionView to appear like a grid with no spacing in between the cells. It was working fantastically after I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28327193/4427300) and implemented it into my own program. I worked on some other files and updated my computer, then I came back and tested this app just to see where I was and for some reason there is horizontal spacing in between cells. I have looked at a few other questions similar to this one, but I'm just wondering how to fix this and why this happened when I didn't change anything related to the layout.

**Here's is what it looks like now:**

[image: Here's what it looks like now]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var model = BoardModel()
var board = Board()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    board = model.newGame(4, 4)

    // Remove the spacing between the cells in collectionView
    // Also make the cells the correct size to form a square/rectangle
    let screenSize: CGRect! = collectionView.bounds
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width/CGFloat(board.columns), height: screenSize.width/CGFloat(board.columns))
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout

    // Center the collectionView
    collectionView.contentInset.top = max((collectionView.frame.height - collectionView.contentSize.height) / 5, 0)

}
```

The reason I'm using the collectionView bounds instead of the UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds is because my collectionView has 20 spacing around all the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40 // convert it if it's not swift 4
let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 40
```

//

or implement

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

     return CGSize.init(width:  , height:  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you the first line alone fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 5.0)
    fileprivate let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

}
// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
        let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (itemsPerRow + 1)
        let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
        let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow
        let heightPerItem = widthPerItem + 21

        return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: heightPerItem)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
        return sectionInsets
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat{
        return sectionInsets.left
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat{

        return 0
    }

}
```