# How to display CollectionViewCell in center in swift 4

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Collectionview cell has a two item in one row, But Collectionview cell doesn't center in my design.

[image]

How can I display the collectionViewCell in center alignment? I want to display like the following image

[image]

I am trying many times, can't display the center of CollectionView. Please Help me!

Comment: try reducing intercellular spacing b/w cells

Answer (score 2):

Working code **Swift 4 | Swift 5**

You need to use **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** method like this

```
class CardListViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    
    // UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout Delegate method

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let leftAndRightPaddings: CGFloat = 45.0
        let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2.0
    
        let width = (collectionView.frame.width-leftAndRightPaddings)/numberOfItemsPerRow
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width) // You can change width and height here as pr your requirement
    
    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: in my tests, when `sizeForItemAt` delegate method runs, the width given by `collectionView.frame.width` is not the actual, runtime width but is still the one taken at design-time, from **I**nterface **B**uilder. So it works only when you test it on the same device used in IB. When you run that on a different device, with different screen size, things stop working. Have you noticed this?

Comment: @Nikunj Kumbhani what to do if I want to change the vertical spacing between cells ?

Comment: @pgokul You can set cell spacing from the storyboard

Comment: Yeah. But the problem was, I created the collection view cell programmatically. So I can't change anything on story board. But I did find the solution though, we can change the `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex` to get appropriate spacing between rows.

Comment: @pgokul You can set that Programatically as well

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani Yeah Thanks for letting me know. But, with the above method I solved the issue so I don't think there is a need to set cell spacing.

Answer (score -1):

Make the following changes:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2.0
    let minimumCellSpacing: CGFloat = 10.0
    let totalSpacing = (numberOfItemsPerRow + 1)*minimumCellSpacing //left + right + in-between padding
    let width = (collectionView.frame.width - totalSpacing)/numberOfItemsPerRow
    return CGSize(width: width, height: width) 

}
```

Once this is done.

Reload your collection view in main thread with a bit delay:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.10) {
   self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This answer does not add anything new to the comparison with the existing one. Using `reloadData` with a delay may help in some cases, but usually it means that you are doing something wrong, also it has nothing to do with this particular questions.

Comment: Have you tried this? if not, please try it and then let me know.

Comment: original answer without `asyncAfter` works for me

Comment: Well.. in some case it does not work unless we use "asyncAfter".