# Issue while collection view cell scroll to center in swift

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have a collection view in my VC, I scroll collection view horizontally, I want to center each cell on scroll horizontally, I have tried a code but when it scrolls it shows next cell more left then the second one .This is my code,

```
fileprivate let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)

gridView.delegate = self
    gridView.dataSource = self
    gridView.register(ItemCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ItemCollectionViewCell")
    gridView.register(UINib(nibName: "ItemCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ItemCollectionViewCell")
    gridView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    gridView.bounces = true
    gridView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    gridView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return auctions?.properties?.count ?? 0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell:ItemCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ItemCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCollectionViewCell;
    cell.propertyData = (auctions?.properties![indexPath.row])!
    if auctions?.status == AuctionStatus.Live.rawValue {
        cell.noOfBidsPlaced.isHidden = false
    }
    else {
        cell.noOfBidsPlaced.isHidden = true
    }
    cell.populateCell()

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = CGSize(width: 335 , height: 337)
    return size
}

//3
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return sectionInsets
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return sectionInsets.left
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return sectionInsets.left

}
```

How I can scroll each cell to center perfectly?
Here is how it shows my collection on start,
[image]

Thats what it shows on scroll, it get cut from left side
[image]

Comment: check this answer .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672069/how-to-display-collectionviewcell-in-center-in-swift-4

Comment: I have tried your given link, there is one issue when I scroll cell. When I scroll each cell is cut off from the left side on the screen, it does not show perfectly centered, i have attached screen in my question please check it out. @Chris

Comment: Need to add paging enabled true and also set the cell width dynamically

Comment: Don't use sectionInsets, adjust your image view in your .xib with left and right spacing. Then use collection view width as cell width

Comment: No, brother it isn't working, i have set collection view leading and trailing from storyboard, and used your func also but still it cut view on left scroll. @SidharthKhanna

Comment: How to set it dynamically? @FaysalAhmed

Comment: Dynamically means based on screen width.  Replace this line  `CGSize(width: 335 , height: 337)` to  `CGSize(width: gridView.frame.width , height: 337)`. Also Paging enabled true.

Comment: I'm assigning it like this and also enabled paging but not working fine. 
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = CGSize(width: 335 , height: 337)
        return size
        
    }. @FaysalAhmed

Comment: Change the width value  `335` to `gridView.frame.width`

Comment: I have done with this now when i scroll it cuts my cell view from right side now on scroll . @FaysalAhmed

Comment: I have made cell and lines to 0 now working fine, but the spacing between cells is very small I want same spacing as in the screenshot. @FaysalAhmed

Comment: You need to handle another view inside the cell content view. This view have the spaces that you want between both sides. Will work I think. This view contains the all components.

Comment: I didn't got the point can explain how to use that view inside content view? @FaysalAhmed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201831/discussion-between-faysal-ahmed-and-hamza).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use static height and width.
call this function.Maybe its helpful for you:-

//    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
//            return CGSize(width: yourCollectionView.frame.size.width, height: yourCollectionView.frame.size.height )
//    }

Comment: Yes it got centered, but i want same spacing between cell as in screen shot. @Gurpreet Singh

Comment: remove all sectionInsets code.i am sure you can also see your collection view is in center and another is not showing.@Hamza