# UICollectionView's contentSize is different when i use flowlayout

Tags: ios

i want to make dynamic height collectionView like below picture, i use collectionView in tableView.

so i set collectionView's data in tableViewDataSource.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell") as? MyTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    cell.setLabelArray(label[indexPath.row])
    cell.titleLabel.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

and then in tableViewCell, i adjust collectionView's height.

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: MyCollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

var labelArray: [String]? {
    didSet {
        myCollectionView.reloadData()
        let height = self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
        self.collectionViewHeight.constant = height
    }
}
...
```

but layout's contentSize is always different when i use flowLayout (like below last picture)

how can i get correct contentSize?? .......

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use sizeForItemAt method for collectionview layout method.
Don't forget to add delegate UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout to viewcontroller.
You can see this answer  [How to set cell spacing and UICollectionView - UICollectionViewFlowLayout size ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325277/how-to-set-cell-spacing-and-uicollectionview-uicollectionviewflowlayout-size-r)