# UICollectionViewLayout item spacing with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I tried to convert [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229350/cell-spacing-in-uicollectionview) Objective-C answer to Swift, but for it always crash on this line:

```
var previousLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = attributesToReturn[i - 1]
```

This is the function:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {

    var attributesToReturn:[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]

    for var i = 0 ; i < attributesToReturn.count ; i++
    {
        var currentLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = attributesToReturn[i]
        var previousLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = attributesToReturn[i - 1]
        var maximumSpacing: CGFloat = 50
        var origin = CGRectGetMaxX(previousLayoutAttributes.frame)
        if origin + maximumSpacing + currentLayoutAttributes.frame.size.width < self.collectionViewContentSize().width
        {
            var frame: CGRect = currentLayoutAttributes.frame
            frame.origin.x = origin + maximumSpacing
            currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame
        }
    }

    return attributesToReturn

}
```

I guess it's because at first there is no i - 1 object.. but how else can I do that?

Comment: Both of the answers in that link are in Swift already... in any case you are attempting to access an item at index -1, which is the reason for the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your code so it checks for a negative index.

```
let origin: CGFloat
if i - 1 >= 0 {
    let previousLayoutAttributes = attributesToReturn[i - 1]
    origin = previousLayoutAttributes.frame.maxX
} else {
    origin = 0
}
```