# How to change space between cells in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to reduce the size between cells in row. 
Now it looks like:

[image]

I'm trying this, for reduce the size between them:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 2, bottom: 10, right: 2)
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

but it doesn't help me. What I do wrong?

Comment: @patchdiaz it's not a duplicate! I've tried this version, but it doesn't work. That's why I created this question

Comment: You're right! Deleted ;)

Comment: Do you want your cells to be left-aligned, i.e. you'll have a lot of empty space on the right?

Comment: What about this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229350/cell-spacing-in-uicollectionview ?

Comment: @TimVermeulen yes, exactly! I want 3 items on a row, with the 2 px space on right, except the last one

Comment: So 2px between each column?

Comment: @TimVermeulen exactly!

Comment: Then can't you simply decrease the width of the collection view?

Comment: @TimVermeulen is it your solution???

Comment: I mean, if you decrease the width of the collection view, the cells will have less space between them.

Comment: @TimVermeulen i want to set the width of cells equal to width / 3 with the right 2px space, as: (width - 4) / 3 in one line with 3 cells

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
//Objective c
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width/3)-20, 100);
    }

// Swift 2.0

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width / 3) - 20, 100)
}

// Swift 3.0
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: CGFloat((collectionView.frame.size.width / 3) - 20), height: CGFloat(100))
}
```

Comment: @ZacharyGover can you back up this "claim" with a creditable source?  Most of Apples modules are still written in Objective-C, and it's still widely used today.

Comment: You do know that I said almost becoming obsolete? Yes some things are still written around Objective-C, although as Apple is updating Swift they are rewriting it all. Although that still means the majority of developers are writing in Swift. My main point that I was trying to get across is to give both answers, as you have now done. Because soon enough it will be obsolete, and people in the future won't be able to understand it if they're new to programming, when they look at this post for help.

Answer (score 30):

Go to the storyboard , right click on collection view and [image]

And Check your minimum spacing between the cell and reduce it to zero .

Comment: Now issue can be in UIcollectionview cell ..... check out the constrains in UICollectionview cell ...... there should not be anytime of padding , rest i need to go through your code

Comment: In story board there are two sections one is collectionview and under collectionview there is collectionview flow layout ....did u check min spacing in both ?

Answer (score 16):

On your code, you have to create a IBOutlet to your collection view, and then assign the collectionViewLayout as such:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 2, bottom: 10, right: 2)
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Comment: You are my hero.

Comment: One more point needs to add : Make sure that collectionview Scroll direction is in "Horizontal" for fixing horizontal cell gap. Otherwise minimumInteritemSpacing may not work.(Tested in Xcode 11.2.1 swift 4.2)

Answer (score 4):

Its simple

```
let layout = contactsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout?.minimumLineSpacing = 8
```

Answer (score 3):

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let collectionWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
            return CGSize(width: collectionWidth, height: collectionWidth/2)
        }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 0
        }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 100
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

### Swift 5 Programmatically

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        //Provide Width and Height According to your need
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 4
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 10
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

        //Make Space as Zero
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

        return UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }()
```

You can provide much more customization inside the `lazy collectionView` Block.

Answer (score 1):

If you create `CollectionView` In `StoryBoard` or `Xib`,Go to `StoryBoard` or `Xib` and set these Values from

[image]

Comment: Can you give some example code of how to achieve this?\

Comment: no, I did not set it from XIB. On XIB I just set collection view cell

Answer (score 0):

(Swift 4)

- Click on collection View in storyboard.
- on right hand side, click size inspector.
- manage and alter the cell size value and you'll figure it out by yourself.