# UICollectionView item spacing can't be adjusted

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am a beginner in iOS development, and I am following a tutorial to implement collection view.

Here is the screenshot of that app :

[image: as we can see, the space between cell and line is quite big]

I want to make that gap between items as close as possible. I have tried to implement the code below:

```
struct StoryBoard {
    static let leftAndRightPaddings : CGFloat = 1.0
    static let numberOfItemsPerRow : CGFloat = 3.0
}

let collectionViewWidth = collectionView?.frame.width
let itemWidth = (collectionViewWidth! - StoryBoard.leftAndRightPaddings) / StoryBoard.numberOfItemsPerRow

let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
```

I have also changed the minimum spacing for cell and line to 0.1 in main storyboard like this:

[image: minimimum spacing in storyboard]

but the gap is still big. what went wrong in here?

Comment: may this help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654129/how-to-change-space-between-cells-in-uicollectionview/35654505#35654505

Comment: Does the imageView fills up on each cell? You can use Debug View Hierarchy to check it

Answer (score 3):

You can manage by use of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method

**For EX.**

Use below method for manage

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        var height = 124.0 // Set whatever you want
         return CGSize(width: (width / 3) - 0.5, height: CGFloat(height)) // Here (width / 3) means 3 cell display in screen horizontally. you can change here 3 or 2 or 4 etc AND "0.5" is space your can change space between two items that you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the item size correctly, as even 1 pixel can cause disturbed layout. Little change for @iPatel answer

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let noOfItemsInRow = 3 // the items in single row
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let totalSpace = 8 + 8 + (noOfItemsInRow * 0.5) //8: side margin, 0.5 is the space between 2 items
    var height = 124.0 // Set whatever you want
     return CGSize(width: ((width - totalSpace) / 3), height: CGFloat(height)) // Here (width / 3) means 3 cell display in screen horizontally. you can change here 3 or 2 or 4 etc
```

}

hope this help