# UICollectionview cell with dynamic height and half width

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

Im trying to create collection view ([Expected View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soM7G.png)) with half width and dynamic height based on given text.

I am trying to achieve this by (Code in ViewController)

```
    let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2), height: 2000.0)
    flowLayout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

And (Code in UICollectionviewCell)

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()
    let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
    var frame = layoutAttributes.frame
    frame.size.height = ceil(size.height)
    layoutAttributes.frame = frame
    return layoutAttributes 
}
```

By using the above code, I can achieve to create collectionview [Actual view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYdCH.png) (half width and dynamic height). But collection view cell height not equal to the adjacent. Actually this collection view cell height should be same as adjacent cell height(which is having the maximum height). How to update the cell size based on the adjacent cell size?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you are set UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize, comment this line and try it

Comment: Just this line is enough     flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2), height: 2000.0)

Comment: try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654129/how-to-change-space-between-cells-in-uicollectionview/35654505#35654505

Comment: @YagneshDobariya: No luck.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> CGSize 
{
//let padding: CGFloat =  5
    let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width / 2
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize , height: 2000 )
}
```

Comment: The above code makes the all cells in collectionview with height 2000. That is not the case here.

Comment: you may change the height according to text that would be in that specific item as we did in a chat view this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your CollectionViewCell class:

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()
    let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
    var newFrame = layoutAttributes.frame
    newFrame.size.height = ceil(size.height)
    newFrame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
    layoutAttributes.frame = newFrame
    return layoutAttributes
}
```

Comment: I have tried this too, but cell size is not updated as expecting.