# UICollectionView vertical separator

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with two columns. I need to put a vertical line through out my collectionView between the columns. Is it possible? Which property of collectionView allows us to achieve it?

Comment: You could probably just increase the spacing between cells: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229350/cell-spacing-in-uicollectionview

Comment: I have already done that. I need to put a vertical line as part of my UI.

Comment: You also can add an UIView inside your collectionViewCell and do some design on it to make it look nicer.

Comment: then set the background color so it will give you that feel

Comment: I was thinking about doing that. Is there any property UICollectionView has similar to UITableView's separatorStyle property?

Comment: nope collectionView does not have property related to separator

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. I suggest you have a look at Decoration views for the collection view - it will allow you to do this. Here is a tutorial: https://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/decorationviews/