# how to maintain spacing between uicollectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my app I am using using `UICollectionView`. I want to set fix space between `UICollectionViewCell`. so how can I do this?

here is my code:

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20

}
```

by this line I can set space between cell?

here is my screenshot please see this. and let me know how can i set fix distance in both landscape or portrait mode

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cell spacing in UICollectionView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229350/cell-spacing-in-uicollectionview)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,you need implementation follow method.

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the spacing between **UICollectionCell** by using the storyboard **Min. spacing** property of UICollectionView.

[image]

Here you have to set Min spacing value for cells and lines.

Hope it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also manage the spacing using the size inspector of Collection View

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvp3g.png

Answer (score 0):

If you want `exact` spacing between the cells you need to calculate the size for the cells that will best fit to allow for the spacing you need without wrapping while considering the `sectionInsets` and CollectionView `bounds`. eg.

```
let desiredSpacing: CGFloat = 20.0

if let layout = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = desiredSpacing
    let totalCellsContentWidth = self.collectionView!.bounds.width - layout.sectionInset.left - layout.sectionInset.right
    let numberOfCellsPerRow: CGFloat = 10
    let numberOfSpacesPerRow = numberOfCellsPerRow - 1
    let cellWidth = (totalCellsContentWidth - (numberOfSpacesPerRow * desiredSpacing) / numberOfCellsPerRow)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
}
```

Assuming your cells are the same size the `minimumLineSpacing` is simple but would otherwise expand to fit the largest cell on the row before wrapping to the next line. As you can see it's the cell spacing that is a bit more complicated.