# Swift : set constraints to UICollectionViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift2, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

I've a scenario where 9 UICollectionViewCell are generated programmatically. It should be arranged in **3*3 format in all iPhone variant.**

Also the **button size to get increased or decreased based on iPhone device.** *For eg.,* In iPhone 4s it should be small so that 3*3 format is arranged properly and in iPhone 6 Plus it should be big enough so that 3*3 format is achieved.

[image: Screenshot 1]

I had tried setting constraints programmatically but didn't get desired result.

[image: Screenshot 2]

**How to set constraints programmatically to UICollectionViewCell such that purpose is achieved?**

Comment: your code please ... for setting cell width and height????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17554270/4601170