# How can I get IndexPath from minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt to set different spacing between items in a collectionview?

Tags: ios, swift

Normally I just use this function:

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

to set some spacing between the items in a collectionView, but the spacing is the same for all items. I would like to set the spacing to be different between some items, depending on some logic that I need to check, the logic will depend on which cell is before and after, so I would need something like IndexPath to check that.

When we want to set size of a cell, we conveniently get IndexPath from the function below, but not from the function above.

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
               sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good way to do it without creating your own layout. There's too much to it to go into it here, but there's tons of good tutorials on the matter. [Here's a good place to start.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19429189/1278026)