# How to make 2 rows in horizontal collection view without using sections

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, horizontal-scrolling, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

The horizontal scrolling in UICollectionView only returns one row and I need to make a horizontal scrolling collection view with 2 rows just like the image below

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs1kt.png :[1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set fix height of the CollectionView and then use sizeForItemAt() under UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout which returns CGSize. You have to manage the cell height something like this.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

            return CGSize(width: 50.0, height: collectionViewHeight / 2) //<-- Manage height and width accordingly.
        }
```

Comment: and how the second row will appear ? coz sizeforitemAt will only manage size .

Comment: Set scroll direction to horizontal and fix height of CollectionView. Now use the above method. Don't forget to Add UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol to your ViewController.

Comment: should i increase the height for collectionview so that it can accommodate two cells ?

Comment: Yes, you can manage accordingly also refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229350/cell-spacing-in-uicollectionview 
 for cell spacing.