# Reduce interitem spacing in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have already looked up:-

[UICollectionView distance between cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514526/uicollectionview-distance-between-cells)

[Cell spacing in UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229350/cell-spacing-in-uicollectionview?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Decrease Space between UICollectionViewCells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071043/decrease-space-between-uicollectionviewcells?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but none of them worked for me.

I also tried implementing the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and implemented

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 3
}
```

but it has no effect on it.

Please have a look at the following screenshots taken in iPhone 7 / iPhone 5s / iPhone 7 Plus (picture order is same)

[image: iPhone 7]

[image: iPhone 5S]

[image: iPhone 7 Plus]

I also looked self-sizing cells, but I don't want self-sizing cells, as my item size is always fixed and meets my requirements.

I have also set the **minimum spacing of cells** in the storyboard but it has no effect on the layout.

**How to reduce the big gap between the two cells (interitem spacing), avoid clipping in the iPhone 5S and also the empty spaces on the right side in the iPhone 7 Plus (you can't see since the background is white)**

Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40261279/4601170

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your cellsize is "Fixed" , you cant avoid the gap because you have hardcoded a fixed width!

You need to calculate the total width of the collectionView.frame and divide it by 2, and also include the spacing between the items, and not a "fixed" size. Quick typed example:

(calculate cellsize)

```
CGFloat spacing = 3.0f
CGFloat itemWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width / 2 - spacing
CGSize totalSize = itemWidth, itemWidth
```

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you. Thanks, the answer seems very much logical.

Comment: @DarkInnocence Np, I strongly suggest you use autolayout for the cell views as you screenshots, so if you have a smalleR/bigger screen, you will keep the design perfect always.

Comment: Works like a charm :D !! Thank you so much. Btw, auto-layout was already implemented.

Comment: @DarkInnocence great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `width` and `height` of each cell in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    float cellWidth = screenWidth / 2.0; //Replace the divisor with the column count requirement. Make sure to have it in float.

    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    screenHeight = screenHeight - 114.0; // Sum of Bottom View & Top View Height

    float cellHeight = screenHeight /(totalArray.count/2);  //totalArray contains item used to show in collectionview

    if(DEFAULT_CELL_HEIGHT > cellHeight){
        cellHeight=DEFAULT_CELL_HEIGHT;
    }

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);

    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Hauzin's answer is fine to get rid of the spacing in different devices. For the spacing between cells (**minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt**), did you make your view controller conform to this protocol (**UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**)?

Comment: Yes, you have implemented the method there. But I am asking if you have really conformed to that protocol in code. `MyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Comment: Yeah I did that. Before Hauzin's solution, I was calculating the wrong width (hardcoded width)