# Swift: setting different spaces between cells in CollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

This might be something pretty obvious but I haven't been able to figure it out. I know how to set different sizes for each cell, and spaces between sections using UICollectionViewLayout. What about different spaces for each cell?

To give you a better idea I currently have:

[image]

and need it to look like this:

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

[Edit] Ok the suggested link as possible duplicated solved my specific problem, but did not answer my question. In this case I wanted to center the the last cell. But what if I want the cell to be slightly more right or slightly more left? That's the actual problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: Is this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40020252/2617369 or are you looking for a more custom spacing? like different spaces for different cells?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center horizontally UICollectionView Cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34267662/how-to-center-horizontally-uicollectionview-cells)

Comment: @MXV did  you solve your problem .. ?