# Dynamic UICollectionView Cell Frame

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Right now, i'm facing an issue.

I manage to wrap the cell's content view to its label, but there's some spacing which doesn't fit to the design. There's some spaces available between the cell

Here's my code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let hastag = Hastag.fetchHastag()[indexPath.row]

    let approximateWidth = view.frame.width - 20
    let size = CGSize(width: approximateWidth, height: 28)
    let attribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)]

    let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: hastag.hastag).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attribute, context: nil)

    return CGSize(width: estimatedFrame.width + 20, height: 26)

}
```

Below is the result

[image]

And this is what i want to achieve, it will be something like this

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here is my full code of collection view data source and delegate. Hastag.hastag is type of string

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Hastag.fetchHastag().count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "hastagCell", for: indexPath) as! HastagCollectionViewCell

    cell.hastag = Hastag.fetchHastag()[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let hastag = Hastag.fetchHastag()[indexPath.row]

    let approximateWidth = view.frame.width - 20
    let size = CGSize(width: approximateWidth, height: 28)
    let attribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)]

    let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: hastag.hastag).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attribute, context: nil)

    return CGSize(width: estimatedFrame.width + 16, height: 26)

}
```

Comment: Making use of Custom layout 'UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout'  would do the trick

Comment: You mean i have to use a library? @Anuraj

Comment: Yes .. I used this one

Comment: Any idea so that i can achieve it without using library? @Anuraj

Comment: No...You may be missing something else. There is another library called TagListView for showing UI like this. It will adjust size automatically .https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView

Comment: @Anuraj thanks dude, i'm finally using your recommended (TagListView) library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several try, i finally give up on customizing cell size and instead i'm using the library [TagListView](https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout`, its not a library just one file. Just add this file to your project and from your `UICollectionView` xib just set the flow layout as `AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout`. It is very easy to use. Please check the below link.

https://github.com/mischa-hildebrand/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: i've tried to put the file, but there are too much errors. can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Are you using xib ? You are creating collectionview manually or in XIB ?

Comment: Check the link everything is there "Setup in Interface Builder" , "Setup in code" if you don't understand something just ask.

Comment: i'm creating the collection view cell inside my storyboard. the errors come from the first time i put the file. there's no error on my code, but the file (AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout.swift) itself has so much errors

Comment: you are using Swift 3 or 4?

Comment: i'm currently using swift 4

Comment: then what error you are getting ? I used the same and its work fine for me

Comment: there are too many undeclared type of 'UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes' errors. can you show me how to use it?

Comment: Give me your gmail id , i will share my file what i m using in my code.

Comment: Can you please upload it to github, so that everyone can see it too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `size(withAttributes:)` function of a `NSString` to give you the `CGSize` of a string with a specific font and size.

Assuming that `Hastag.hastag` is a `String` I think the following should work:

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let hastag = Hastag.fetchHastag()[indexPath.row]
        let title = hastag.hastag as NSString
        let titleSize = title.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)])
        return CGSize(width: titleSize.width + 20, height: 26)
    }
}
```

**Note** that your `ViewController` must implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol and you must set your `ViewController` as the `delegate` for the `UICollectionView` for this to work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for answering, but your code returns the same as my code

Comment: hmm...then there must be something else different in your setup...because the above work for me :) Could you show me how you have defined the layout maybe?

Comment: check my updates please ;). on the storyboard, i set constraint for my collection view 8,8,16,16 (top, bottom, trailing, leading) in case you need to know that

Comment: @Jason I've updated my answer, make sure that you implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and add your view controller as a `delegate` (see this fine answer for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12925529/4063602)

Comment: OK. And you can see that your method is called if you place an breakpoint in it?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: If you add a breakpoint in your sizeForItemAt: method, and then run your code, is the breakpoint then hit? If it isn’t then that is why it isn’t working

Comment: It must be hit the method. Because if it doesn't, then the cell doesn't resize to the label inside of it. But I'll try to put the breakpoint. I'll give you the info soon